# In a getter method, Should I clone a String being returned?

Tags: java, string, field, getter-setter, cloning

In Java, is it advisable to create another String when returning fields that are Strings in a getter method.  my_name is a String field of a class.

```
public String getName()
{
    String rString = my_name.toString();
    return rString;
}
```

Answer (score 12):

> In Java, is it advisable to create another String when returning
>   fields that are Strings in a getter method. my_name is a String field
>   of a class.

**No**, there is no point in doing so. Since Strings in Java are *immutable*, when you try to modify the string returned by the `getter` method (i.e. re-assign the String reference currently pointing to a string object, to a different string), it will create a new string, and assign a reference to that string to the current string reference, hence detaching it from the original string.

However, if you have `mutable` fields, like an `array`, then in that case, it is advisable to return a defensive copy of it, if you want your object to be immutable.

Comment: "any modification done to it outside the class" What's *it* in this case?

Comment: In point of fact, you _can't_ modify a `String`; there's no such thing as a "modification."

Comment: For immutable objects no need of cloning

Answer (score 2):

No.  In Java strings are immutable, so it cannot be modified by whoever is calling the getter.

Also, due to the way Java pools Strings to re-use them, your code would do the exact same thing as directly returning the field.